# Session-State In-Process (InProc) mode: When is it forgotten?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

I'm using the InProc session-state mode in my web application.

In order to test the client's behavior on a session loss I restarted the web server, first just iis, then the entire machine. Both actions did not lead to a session loss.

This puzzles me: The session is stored on memory, right? How can the session be retained after the machine restarted? Does IIS dump the sessions on disk on a restart? If so, where is this documented and how do I flush the sessions for testing purposes?

I'm using IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012.

EDIT: I don't know whether I actually lose the *session* - what I know is that my cookie is still accepted. (I don't actually use any "session", I just need to authenticate the user.) It could be that the authentication ticket is usable even after the actual session is lost, as is suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx).

EDIT: Also look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) for more information about the forms authentication cookie and what's in it.

Comment: Are you sure about that? InProc storage should not survive not only the server restart but even the restart of the worker process.

Comment: @WiktorZychla It probably doesn't, see my edit.

Comment: That changes everything. Cookies of course are accepted, even if the server restarts. I suggest you delete the question as it doesn't make much sense now.

Comment: You probably confused yourself of what is cookie and what is session. In-proc sessions are gone, once the worker process shuts down.

Comment: I don't think it's obvious that this is how it works at all - I always presumed that the authentication key in the cookie is merely an opaque identifier of a session. Of course it's documented, but I was so convinced that this is how it works that I didn't bother to delve into it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what I assumed, the authentication entry in the cookie isn't merely an opaque identifier of a session, but actually a encrypted username with an expiry time. It is not directly related to a session at all, and its validity is independent of the validity of any sessions.

That means that **the expiry of authentication and the loss of the session are two distinct events that *usually* occur at different times**.

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) and this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx) for more information.